# Refreshing the angular 2 application is generating Error 404 - Page not found exception

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular2-routing

I am developing Angular 2 application that is using KendoUI datagrid in asp.net web application. I have set `index.html` as the startup page. When i press F5, `index.html` loads. Click on the Risks Menu displays the datagrid with data that is defined in `risk-list.component.html` page. Its URL is `localhost/risks`. If I press F5, I get **404 page not found error**. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be and how can I fix it?

This is my code:

**risk-list.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk';
import { RiskService } from './risk.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'rm-risks',
    templateUrl: '/app/risk-list.component.html',
    providers: [RiskService]
})

export class RiskListComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Risk List';
     risks: Risk[];

    constructor(private _riskService: RiskService) {
        console.log(this.risks);
    }

    getRisks(): void {
        this._riskService.getRisks().then(risks => this.risks = risks);

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getRisks();
    }
};
```

**risk-list.component.html**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="risks">
    <kendo-grid-column field="reference" title="Reference" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="insuredName" title="Insured Name">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="inceptionDate" title="Inception Date" width="230">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="riskType" title="Risk Type" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Status" title="Status">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="grossPremium" title="Gross Premium" width="230">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="allocatedTo" title="Allocated To" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="allocatedCompany" title="Allocated Company">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120">
        <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled />
        </template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**risk.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk';
import { Risks } from './mock-risk';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';


@Injectable()
export class RiskService {

    getRisks(): Promise<Risk[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(Risks);
    }

}
```

**risk.ts**

```
export class Risk {
    riskId: number;
    reference: string;
    insuredName: string;
    inceptionDate: string;
    riskType: string;
    status: string;
    grossPremium: number;
    allocatedTo: string;
    allocatedCompany: string;

}
```

**mock-risk.ts**

```
import { Risk } from './risk'

export const Risks: Risk[] = [

    {

        "riskId": 1,
        "reference": "HISC9308336",
        "insuredName": "SA 84161",
        "inceptionDate": "March 19, 2016",
        "riskType": "Quote",
        "status": "Indication",
        "grossPremium": 100,
        "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
        "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
    },
    {

        riskId: 2,
        reference: "HISC9308337",
        insuredName: "SA 84161",
        inceptionDate: 'April 22, 2016',
        riskType: 'Quote',
        status: 'Indication',
        grossPremium: 300,
        allocatedTo: 'Broker User',
        allocatedCompany: 'Broker'
    }

];
```

**risks.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RiskListComponent } from './risk-list.component';
import { RiskService } from './risk.service';
import { RiskRoutingModule } from './risks-routing.module';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RiskRoutingModule,
        GridModule

    ],
    declarations: [
        RiskListComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        RiskService
    ]
})
export class RisksModule { }
```

**risks-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RiskListComponent } from './risk-list.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'risks', component: RiskListComponent }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class RiskRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Angular Router</h1>
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/risks" routerLinkActive="active">Risks</a>

</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl:'/app/app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RiskListComponent } from './risk-list.component'
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([

            { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solved by implementing `HashLocationStrategy` which adds `#` to all your routes. For example, `http://localhost/myComponent` becomes `http://localhost/#/myComponent`. You achieve this by adding `HashLocationStrategy` to `AppModule`'s providers:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

Of course, you need to import `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` from `@angular/common`:

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

For more information, check [Angular 2 Router & Navigation - Browser URL Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles).

Comment: The link that you have shared tells me to put RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/ in the app.module.ts. In my example i believe it is app-routing.module.ts. But in my app-routing.module.ts , I have  RouterModule.forRoot([

            { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
        ])   How do I add this line here as it gives me compilation error

Comment: @Tom In your case, it should be `RouterModule.forRoot([ { path: '', component: HomeComponent } ], { useHash: true })`

Comment: Thanks the hashStrategy worked. I have read the LocationStrategy is default. If I set the useHash = false and refresh the browser , it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser is refreshed it will send a get request to the server with the current url, since angular is using HTML 5 style navigation, the url will make no sense to the server. Either update your server to serve the index.html on particular paths or use the `HashLocationStrategy`.

The benefit of using HTML 5 style navigation is that you can mix your angular app with server rendered pages.

An example of getting this working with asp.net: http://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2015/05/a-tale-of-angular-html5mode-aspnet-mvc.html

More reading on angular: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve it using my example as I am not able to correlate your example with mine. Your example is making api calls

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get rid of this Error404 page not found, you should import `HashLocationStrategy` to `appModule.ts`

When I previously worked on Angular, Same type of error raised in my Project, so that I created a simple repository for this kind of error (404 Page Not Found), it may help you. Here is the link -> [AngularAppExample](https://github.com/suryareddyc1/RouterApp-A4)